# DVWA login error

Tags: php, authentication, fatal-error

I can't login to my DVWA.

i searched the web but cant find the answer. Database is created and al seems wel, but when i want to login i get an error message:

Fatal error: [MySQLConverterToo] Fix the mysql_escape_string() call! This code does not work. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dvwa/login.php on line 11

my config.inc.php:

```
<?php

# If you are having problems connecting to the MySQL database and all of the variables below are correct
# try changing the 'db_server' variable from localhost to 127.0.0.1. Fixes a problem due to sockets.
#   Thanks to @digininja for the fix.

# Database management system to use
$DBMS = 'MySQL';
#$DBMS = 'PGSQL'; // Currently disabled

# Database variables
#   WARNING: The database specified under db_database WILL BE ENTIRELY DELETED during setup.
#   Please use a database dedicated to DVWA.
$_DVWA = array();
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = '127.0.0.1';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';

# Only used with PostgreSQL/PGSQL database selection.
$_DVWA[ 'db_port '] = '5432';

# ReCAPTCHA settings
#   Used for the 'Insecure CAPTCHA' module
#   You'll need to generate your own keys at: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_public_key' ]  = '6LdK7xITAAzzAAJQTfL7fu6I-0aPl8KHHieAT_yJg';

$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_private_key' ] = '6LdK7xITAzzAAL_uw9YXVUOPoIHPZLfw2K1n5NVQ';

# Default security level
#   Default value for the secuirty level with each session.
#   The default is 'impossible'. You may wish to set this to either 'low', 'medium', 'high' or impossible'.
$_DVWA[ 'default_security_level' ] = 'impossible';

# Default PHPIDS status
#   PHPIDS status with each session.
#   The default is 'disabled'. You can set this to be either 'enabled' or 'disabled'.
$_DVWA[ 'default_phpids_level' ] = 'disabled';

# Verbose PHPIDS messages
#   Enabling this will show why the WAF blocked the request on the blocked request.
#   The default is 'disabled'. You can set this to be either 'true' or 'false'.
$_DVWA[ 'default_phpids_verbose' ] = 'false';

?>
```

and my login.php:

```
<?php

define( 'DVWA_WEB_PAGE_TO_ROOT', '' );
require_once DVWA_WEB_PAGE_TO_ROOT . 'dvwa/includes/dvwaPage.inc.php';

dvwaPageStartup( array( 'phpids' ) );

dvwaDatabaseConnect();

if( isset( $_POST[ 'Login' ] ) ) {
    // Anti-CSRF
    checkToken( $_REQUEST[ 'user_token' ], $_SESSION[ 'session_token' ], 'login.php' );

    $user = $_POST[ 'username' ];
    $user = stripslashes( $user );
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string( $user );

    $pass = $_POST[ 'password' ];
    $pass = stripslashes( $pass );
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string( $pass );
    $pass = md5( $pass );

    $query = ("SELECT table_schema, table_name, create_time
                FROM information_schema.tables
                WHERE table_schema='{$_DVWA['db_database']}' AND table_name='users'
                LIMIT 1");
    $result = @mysql_query( $query );
    if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) != 1 ) {
        dvwaMessagePush( "First time using DVWA.<br />Need to run 'setup.php'." );
        dvwaRedirect( DVWA_WEB_PAGE_TO_ROOT . 'setup.php' );
    }

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user='$user' AND password='$pass';";
    $result = @mysql_query( $query ) or die( '<pre>' . mysql_error() . '.<br />Try <a href="setup.php">installing again</a>.</pre>' );
    if( $result && mysql_num_rows( $result ) == 1 ) {    // Login Successful...
        dvwaMessagePush( "You have logged in as '{$user}'" );
        dvwaLogin( $user );
        dvwaRedirect( DVWA_WEB_PAGE_TO_ROOT . 'index.php' );
    }

    // Login failed
    dvwaMessagePush( 'Login failed' );
    dvwaRedirect( 'login.php' );
}

$messagesHtml = messagesPopAllToHtml();

Header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');    // HTTP/1.1
Header( 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8' );      // TODO- proper XHTML headers...
Header( 'Expires: Tue, 23 Jun 2009 12:00:00 GMT' );     // Date in the past

// Anti-CSRF
generateSessionToken();

echo "
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">

<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />

        <title>Login :: Damn Vulnerable Web Application (DVWA) v" . dvwaVersionGet() . "</title>

        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"" . DVWA_WEB_PAGE_TO_ROOT . "dvwa/css/login.css\" />

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id=\"wrapper\">

    <div id=\"header\">

    <br />

    <p><img src=\"" . DVWA_WEB_PAGE_TO_ROOT . "dvwa/images/login_logo.png\" /></p>

    <br />

    </div> <!--<div id=\"header\">-->

    <div id=\"content\">

    <form action=\"login.php\" method=\"post\">

    <fieldset>

            <label for=\"user\">Username</label> <input type=\"text\" class=\"loginInput\" size=\"20\" name=\"username\"><br />


            <label for=\"pass\">Password</label> <input type=\"password\" class=\"loginInput\" AUTOCOMPLETE=\"off\" size=\"20\" name=\"password\"><br />

            <br />

            <p class=\"submit\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\" name=\"Login\"></p>

    </fieldset>

    " . tokenField() . "

    </form>

    <br />

    {$messagesHtml}

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <!-- <img src=\"" . DVWA_WEB_PAGE_TO_ROOT . "dvwa/images/RandomStorm.png\" /> -->
    </div > <!--<div id=\"content\">-->

    <div id=\"footer\">

    <p>" . dvwaExternalLinkUrlGet( 'http://www.dvwa.co.uk/', 'Damn Vulnerable Web Application (DVWA)' ) . " is a RandomStorm OpenSource project.</p>

    </div> <!--<div id=\"footer\"> -->

    </div> <!--<div id=\"wrapper\"> -->

    </body>

</html>";

?>
```

I only changed:

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';
```

because otherwise it wouldn't create..

What's going on?

I am totally new to this, but i am dying too learn! ;-)

Answer (score 11):

I had same problem,You can try this..

1. Go to url and enter 127.0.0.1/dvwa/setup.php and click on create reset database.
2. Now login as admin and password.

Answer (score 1):

Enter `"admin"` as userid

Enter `"password"` as a password

Answer (score 0):

//   This solution worked perfectly for me , try once. changes are made on

```
    $_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = 'localhost';
    $_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
    $_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
    $_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';
    $_DVWA[ 'db_port'] = '3306';
```

// change the db_port according to xampp control panel mysql port .

```
 // finally code look like this and it worked.


    <?php

# If you are having problems connecting to the MySQL database and all of the variables below are correct
# try changing the 'db_server' variable from localhost to 127.0.0.1. Fixes a problem due to sockets.


# Database management system to use
    $DBMS = 'MySQL';
    #$DBMS = 'PGSQL'; // Currently disabled

# Database variables
#   WARNING: The database specified under db_database WILL BE ENTIRELY DELETED during setup.
#   Please use a database dedicated to DVWA.
#
# If you are using MariaDB then you cannot use root, you must use create a dedicated DVWA user.
#   See README.md for more information on this.
    $_DVWA = array();
    $_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = 'localhost';
    $_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
    $_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
    $_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';
    $_DVWA[ 'db_port'] = '3306';

# ReCAPTCHA settings
#   Used for the 'Insecure CAPTCHA' module
#   You'll need to generate your own keys at: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin
    $_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_public_key' ]  = '';
    $_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_private_key' ] = '';

# Default security level
#   Default value for the security level with each session.
#   The default is 'impossible'. You may wish to set this to either 'low', 'medium', 'high' or impossible'.
    $_DVWA[ 'default_security_level' ] = 'low';

# Default PHPIDS status
#   PHPIDS status with each session.
#   The default is 'disabled'. You can set this to be either 'enabled' or 'disabled'.
    $_DVWA[ 'default_phpids_level' ] = 'disabled';

# Verbose PHPIDS messages
#   Enabling this will show why the WAF blocked the request on the blocked request.
#   The default is 'disabled'. You can set this to be either 'true' or 'false'.
     $_DVWA[ 'default_phpids_verbose' ] = 'false';

     ?>
```